# about a stuck bitcoin transaction

Tags: security

I sent 24mbtc over a week ago with the transaction number abef483d268dc61214fd5bf25c602256cf447aa65bec2e539fee42f59a3b90b3 
the person i sent to still says, they have not received anything yet the transaction says in my wallet it is confirmed. What could be the problem?

Comment: there is no 24mbtc output in your transaction.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: while your transaction did go through (see below), you sent a different amount (~11 or ~19 mBTC depending on which is the change address) from what you said the recipient wanted.

Looking at https://blockchain.info/tx/abef483d268dc61214fd5bf25c602256cf447aa65bec2e539fee42f59a3b90b3, it seems that your transaction is not stuck at all. It has been confirmed over a thousand times as of today. So there's three possibilities here:

a) the recipient of the transaction doesn't know how his wallet works and is somehow unable to see the received transaction

b) they gave you a wrong address or you mistyped or mis-copypasted it (which would mean the coins were sent to an address somebody else owns, or nobody at all)

c) the recipient is lying to you.

Comment: the recipient has not received 24mbtc  because the sender did not send this amount in specified transaction

Comment: I seem to have been asleep